# Mongo 3.2 Boolean If Matched in Array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

basically I'm trying to create a boolean field "focus" in a query that is true if a field "focusStores" contains a certain store.

Example: 
If a product as the following focus stores - ["AAA","BBB"] and if I'm using the store "AAA" as a search criteria the focus field should be true.

This is currently my best try. Any help would be appreciated!

```
   db.getCollection('Products').aggregate([
      {
        $project: {
          sku:  1,
          focusStores : 1,
          focusTmp : {$focusStores: {$in : 'AAA'}}
        }
      }
    ])
```

Comment: You can use $cond e.g. focusTmp : { $cond: { if: {$focusStores: {$in : 'AAA'}}, then: true, else: false } }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For MongoDB 3.2 use [`$setIsSubset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/):

```
   db.getCollection('Products').aggregate([
      {
        $project: {
          sku:  1,
          focusStores : 1,
          focusTmp : { $setIsSubset: [ ["AAA"], { "$ifNull": [ "$focusStores", [] } ] }
        }
      }
    ])
```

You probably read [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) which is a MongoDB 3.4 operator, and got the syntax incorrect. Should be :

```
   db.getCollection('Products').aggregate([
      {
        $project: {
          sku:  1,
          focusStores : 1,
          focusTmp : { $in: [ "AAA", { "$ifNull": [ "$focusStores", [] ] } ] }
        }
      }
    ])
```

But only when you have a supporting version of course.

In both cases you wrap with [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) to cater for missing properties.

Comment: I'm getting this error when trying the $setIsSubset "both operands of $setIsSubset must be arrays. Second argument is of type: EOO"

Comment: @MMrj Does your question not state that focusStores is an array of `["AAA","BBB"]`? Because if it's not an array then that property is the one that needs wrapping in `[]`. If neither are arrays then you just want `$eq`. But I'm reading your question as if it were an array, since that's the question you appear to be asking.

Comment: yes, the field should be an array but there are some cases where its null, maybe thats the problem